# How to change the size of a UISlider thumb when seeking

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, uislider

I'd like to make my UISlider thumb size change while I scrub the slider, much like how the seeker works in Apple Music or Spotify. Is this possible to do with a vanilla UISlider? Any pointers on how to do this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a normal and larger thumb image with the sizes you want as PDF and add it to the .xcassets.

Then use the following lines of code:

```
let normal = UIImage(named: "thumbSmall")
slider.setThumbImage(normal, for: .normal)
let highlighted = UIImage(named: "thumbLarger")
slider.setThumbImage(highlighted, for: .highlighted)
```

Then during sliding the larger thumb image is shown.

A short test looks like this:

[image: thumb size during sliging]